# Что отвечает за конвертацию named color в hex color в стилях?

Tags: webpack, less

В .less есть стили для кнопки Apple Pay, например `-apple-pay-button-style: white;`, где `white` - параметр, а не цвет. После компиляции на выходе в стилях `-apple-pay-button-style: #FFF;` Что может отвечать за такое преобразование и как можно это отключить для конкретной строки?

В `css-loader` ничего не настроено